# Default values for AdoNetAppender parameter

Tags: log4net, adonetappender

I am using log4net with AdoNetAppender. It logs all log info into a table. This table actually has 2 Integer columns (can be null).

Here is the relevant part of my log4net config:

```xml
<commandText value="INSERT INTO ActivityLog ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[DealID]) 
                 VALUES (@log_date,@thread,@log_level,@logger,@message,@DealID)" />

 //other parameters hten DealID
<parameter>
      <parameterName value="@DealID" />
      <dbType value="Int32" />
       <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{DealID}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
```

What I found out was if I don't explicitly set using something like `log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["DealID"] = DealID;` it throws me an exception:

```
System.FormatException occurred
  Message="Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32."
  Source="System.Data"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType)
  InnerException: System.FormatException
       Message="Input string was not in a correct format."
       Source="mscorlib"
       StackTrace:
            at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
            at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
            at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
            at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType)
       InnerException:
```

I would have to set it like:

`log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["DealID"] = 0;`

Is there anyway that I can set a default parameter value in my log4net config for this Int32 field so that I don't need to set it explicitly to 0 if no value is supplied? And it makes me wonder why it does not happen to fields which are set as varchar (though no value is supplied to them).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Change your appender:

```xml
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@DealID" />
    <dbType value="Int32" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">  <!-- notice this -->
        <key value="DealID" />  <!-- and notice this instead of the pattern layout -->
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

And to give credit, I found it [from this thread](http://www.l4ndash.com/Log4NetMailArchive/tabid/70/forumid/1/tpage/1/view/topic/postid/15968/Default.aspx). (And a bunch of other searching trying to do the same thing.